# AWS S3 Download Link Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently experiencing an issue with AWS S3 Buckets. I've successfully managed to set the roles and permission for specific objects and make some of them downloadable for everyone via a specific link.

```
https://<sub-domain>.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/path/path/a87cd6a9-a2d9-4231-beb3-6b1e76d90490/8e958264-4baf-4fbe-918b-c30d9d450671.jpg
```

This link is a download link for an image and when I click it the browser recommends me to "Stay Safe" and the connection to this Server is not privat / secure.

Any ideas how I can verify the SSL Certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `https` for downloading objects from S3. Its only available through `http`, thus there are no certificates to validate.  For ssl you need to use CloudFront with S3:

- [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)
- [Setup AWS S3 static website hosting using SSL (ACM)](https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/setup-aws-s3-static-website-hosting-using-ssl-acm-34d41d32e394)

Comment: This is a thoroughly incorrect answer, I'm afraid.  HTTPS works perfectly fine on S3 everywhere except with custom domains or on the web site hosting endpoints, which always include some variant of `s3-website` in the hostname, and the URL here does not reflect either possibility.  The problem here is that they're using a bucket name with a dot in it, so the wildcard cert offered by S3 doesn't match, as would be expected.  Dots are allowed in bucket names but actually using them is a mistake that should be avoided.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks Michael for clarification. You are correct, my mistake. If you could please make the correct awnser, I will upvote it and reference in mine.